# ffmpeg ... -i audio.ac3 -c:a copy ... is converting Dolby Digital 2-channel surround to stereo. How to fix?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Please note, unlike a number of posters on the forum, I am not trying to convert surround to stereo or perform a conversion of any kind.  I just want an existing 2-channel ac3 Dolby Digital surround audio track to copy as is, without re-encoding.  But even though I am using -c:a copy, the audio in the output file is no longer interpreted as surround, but stereo, even though it continues to be identified as 2-channel Dolby Digital.  Any hints as to why that would be and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

More specifically, I have been experimenting with upscaling some SD videos to HD using Topaz Video Enhance AI.  (Generally, it's working well.)  The best way to do that is to write a folder full of still images, one per frame.  I then use ffmpeg to stitch those together with the original soundtrack (extracted with ffmpeg successfully *retaining* surround sound!), producing the final movie.  Or it would be the final movie if the audio copy behaved itself.  It doesn't.  Instead of using the three front channels, the copied audio is treated as stereo.

I extracted the audio like so:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -y -c:a copy audio.ac3`

I can play that audio.ac3 file in VLC and it still produces surround sound.

I convert the stills to a movie and add that audio back in like so:

`ffmpeg -framerate 25 -start_number 0 -i "%06d.tif" -i audio.ac3 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`

(The source video was PAL, hence that framerate.)

However, when I play out.mp4 in VLC, it now uses only the left and right channels.  Why would that be, and how can I fix it?

Currently I use MKVToolNix to put the upscaled video together with the original surround audio track, and that produces what I want.  I'm just hoping to eliminate that last step, and understand what's going wrong.

I doubt it's relevant, but this is on a Mac running Catalina 10.15.7 using a brew-built ffmpeg 4.2.1.  Looks like I need to update that.

EDIT: I have a simpler way to expose the issue...

Using [this test.ac3 file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XCtRedHKdkAtM4_A9JiN3L6AMKvoxxZw/view?usp=sharing), simply copy the audio to a new file:

`ffmpeg -i test.ac3 -c:a copy -y test_copy.ac3`

That works, with test_copy.ac3 playing back in surround sound in, for example, VLC.

Instead, copy the audio into an otherwise empty .mkv file:

`ffmpeg -i test.ac3 -c:a copy -y test_copy.mkv`

That also works, with test_copy.mkv playing back in surround sound.

However, copy the audio into an otherwise empty .mp4 file:

`ffmpeg -i test.ac3 -c:a copy -y test_copy.mp4`

This fails, playing the audio back in stereo instead of surround.

Comment: Thanks, @llogan, I will try that. In the meantime I've discovered something quite odd, but very convenient for me. Changing absolutely nothing except replacing "out.mp4" by "out.mkv" fixes the problem. The problem is limited to when ffmpeg is copying the ac3 to a .mp4 container, and works fine when copying to a .mkv container. I wonder if there is some vestigial code from back when mp4 did not support ac3 that is getting triggered.

Comment: I updated to the latest release, 4.3.1, rather than HEAD. It made no difference.

Comment: I tried your suggested command, pulling the audio from the original .mkv file rather than going through an audio.ac3 intermediary. It made no difference.

Comment: I have a simpler example of the problem, narrowing it down to just moving ac3 surround into an mp4 file, but to express it properly I'll need to edit it into the question.

Comment: FTR, --HEAD produces the same result.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem. Is it due to ffmpeg or VLC? In other words, is it a muxing issue, or a demuxing/decoding issue? If you use a different tool to mux, does it work in VLC? Does the MP4 from ffmpeg work in other players, including non-FFmpeg based players?