# Changing frequency of surround ac3 audio in ffmpeg changes it to stereo

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I've been experimenting with using ffmpeg to adjust for the undesirable speed up that happens when 24 fps films are shown at 25 fps in PAL videos.  (Which seems to happen a lot.)

I've mastered changing the video framerate without re-encoding.  That's good.

I've mastered changing the audio sample rate allowing the pitch to change, as desired.  That's good.

However, for a particular project, the audio is Dolby Digital surround sound in an ac3 2-channel track to start with.  And after adjusting for the frequency change, it only plays back in stereo.  Why would that be, and how can I fix it?

To simplify the problem, I've extracted a [short test.ac3 audio clip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XCtRedHKdkAtM4_A9JiN3L6AMKvoxxZw/view?usp=sharing) from the 25fps source.

Listened to in, for example, VLC, it clearly plays in surround sound, with the initial voice in the center channel.

To demonstrate that ffmpeg has no trouble simply copying the surround ac3 into another file, one can run this:

`ffmpeg -i test.ac3 -c:a copy -y test_copy.ac3`

Playing back test_copy.ac3 the clip clearly has remained in surround sound.

However, if one adjusts the frequency of the track like so:

`ffmpeg -i test.ac3 -filter:a "asetrate=48000*24/25" -y test24.ac3`

Playing back test24.ac3 produces only stereo sound, with the voice in left and right channels, and nothing in the center channel.

[ffmpeg also has trouble simply copying this ac3 track into an otherwise empty .mp4 file](https://superuser.com/questions/1624927/ffmpeg-i-audio-ac3-ca-copy-is-converting-dolby-digital-2-channel-surr), so it appears 2-channel Dolby Digital surround sound in an ac3 track is a very fragile thing in ffmpeg, but one problem at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Dolby Surround and Dolby ProLogic [work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolby_Pro_Logic#Dolby_Surround) by encoding all channels in a certain way into two channels.

So, guess: your sample rate change breaks either detection or the complete encoding, depending on what you are using to play it back, so you only get the "real" two channels.

Potential workaround: Try to find a software decoder (might be difficult because of licensing issues), extract all channels from those two channels, change the rate on all channels, and then play them back as true surround sound.